# Attaching event to sublayout

Tags: android, android-layout, event-handling

I have a layout inside another layout.

```
<GridLayout ... >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/id_daily_readings_small" ... > ... </RelativeLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I want to add a touch event to the relative layout and all its contents so that touching anywhere inside it will fire the event. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_daily_readings_small);
rl.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
     {
         // do your work
     }
});
```

Then you can compare the `MotionEvent` to decide what to do if you want to change the behavior based on pressing down/up/etc... Check the Docs links below for more information to make it work for what exactly you need.

[OnTouchListener Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

[MotionEvent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: The answer should have been obvious to me. I was thinking too much. Thanks for helping.